# XStream and -XstartOnFirstThread

Tags: java

I recently stumbled over the following behaviour.
I have an application which needs the -XstartOnFirstThread to be set. And if I set this flag to the VM and try to deserialize any objects in another thread it simply hangs.
See the example below:

```java
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
public class XStreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            XStream x = new XStream();
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            String xml = x.toXML(r);

            Object o = x.fromXML(xml);
            System.out.println("ready");
            return;
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:
[image]

Since it seems to block at the ClassLoader I guess there is the issue to be found. I did the same test using `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` and this time it worked.

So there must be an issue with awt classes and using startOnFirstThread?!
Maybe someone can give my a hint in the right direction, what is causing these problems.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I just found the problem.
When I do a `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();`
in the constructor or static initializer of my test class it doesn't hang any more.

I'm not sure about the reason for that but it seems that `System.loadLibrary("awt")` is done on the wrong thread or with the wrong classloader, when XStream tries to init an awt class.